# Q: Cordova Phonegap Geolocation getting the right speed?

Tags: android, cordova, geolocation, gps, phonegap

I made an app that tracks users location now i need to get the speed also. I manage to put `position.coords.speed` but it always shows 0. I noticed that the gps tracker/icon is not actively tracking. What is the best practice on tracking the speed of the user? I am using the plugin cordova-plugin-geolocation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you requested high accuracy in the options when requesting location? For example:

```
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, {
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  timeout: 30000,
  maxAge: 0
});
```

If `position.coords.speed` is zero and the gps/location icon is not shown in the taskbar, this might be the cause.

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply and thank you for answering my question. I recently did this earlier and i fixed my problem as well. This is what i did too so i want to mark this question as the answer. Thank you again!